# Error when opening UnrealEngine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

Im new to UnrealEngine but I have worked with unity before. im trying to create a new unreal engine file but I keep getting this error every time I try (Can not compile, basically):

```
    The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Visual Studio?

    Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.10/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe test Development Win64 -project="C:/Users/abdel/Desktop/gamemaking/Unreal/BuildingEscape/test/test.uproject" -rocket -editorrecompile -progress -noubtmakefiles -2015
@progress push 5%
Parsing headers for testEditor
  Running UnrealHeaderTool "C:/Users/abdel/Desktop/gamemaking/Unreal/BuildingEscape/test/test.uproject" "C:\Users\abdel\Desktop\gamemaking\Unreal\BuildingEscape\test\Intermediate\Build\Win64\testEditor\Development\UnrealHeaderTool.manifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -rocket -installed
Reflection code generated for testEditor in 7.1584488 seconds
@progress pop
Performing 8 actions (2 in parallel)
[2/8] Resource PCLaunch.rc
PCH.test.h.cpp
[3/8] Resource ModuleVersionResource.rc.inl
testGameMode.cpp
test.generated.cpp
C:\Users\abdel\Desktop\gamemaking\Unreal\BuildingEscape\test\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Inc\test\test.generated.cpp: error C4599: '/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE': command line argument number 228 does not match precompiled headerC:\Users\abdel\Desktop\gamemaking\Unreal\BuildingEscape\test\Source\test\testGameMode.cpp: error C4599: '/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE': command line argument number 228 does not match precompiled header

testCharacter.cpp
C:\Users\abdel\Desktop\gamemaking\Unreal\BuildingEscape\test\Source\test\testCharacter.cpp: error C4599: '/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE': command line argument number 228 does not match precompiled header
test.cpp
C:\Users\abdel\Desktop\gamemaking\Unreal\BuildingEscape\test\Source\test\test.cpp: error C4599: '/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE': command line argument number 228 does not match precompiled header
-------- End Detailed Actions Stats -----------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: C:\Users\abdel\Desktop\gamemaking\Unreal\BuildingEscape\test\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-test.dll
Total build time: 26.15 seconds
```

I have visual studio downloaded and when I try to open it in Visual Studio, I get a build error.

please help :)

Comment: What is your vs version? UE4.10 only supports vs2015 and 2013 in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at
https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/VisualStudioSetup/
and check that you are using the correct Visual Studio version.

Also, is there a reason that you are using Unreal Engine 4.10 instead of the newest version, even though you are just starting with UE and, I assume, you don't have any previous projects?